# Php check file gives different output on localhost and on web server

Tags: php, apache, magento, xampp

I have this issue that I have used alot of hours to try to fix, but no success in doing so.

To put it as simple as possible, I have this php-check file to see if I meet the requirements
of an installation. This php file runs as expected on a webserver with this output:

http://migo.no/temp/magento-check-web.jpg

But when I run the same php file on localhost I get this really weird output combined with
php code which makes no sense to me:

http://migo.no/temp/magento-check-localhost.jpg

So I am trying to figure out this problem because I want to be able to run Magento on localhost. I have followed the instructions that can be found here:

magentocommerce[dot]com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/installing_on_windows_with_xampp_and_wamp

And this is the magento-check.php file:

magentocommerce[dot]com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-know-if-my-server-is-compatible-with-magento

I have even checked all the requirements manually by running phpinfo() and searching for terms, they are all enabled, I have the newest php and mysql installed that came with the
newest xampp.

In the end I have absolutely no idea why i do not get a simple output of what I am missing, but basicly an output combined with php code that I can't seem to figure out.

Best regards,
Alexander

Comment: Which php version are you running? `php --version` or phpinfo() might help with that.

Comment: The only thing i can see is checking your `short_open_tag` value in php.ini. If it's not On, it can give some weird outputs like that (if short tags are used, that is). If it's not that, can't really help you much more, soz.

Comment: I think you local setting is not allow using `short_open_tag`. Just replace `<?` with `<?php` in your `magento-check.php` file